# How'd I refer to list size?

Tags: java, list

It's my first time on stackoverflow, forgive me my terrible formating I swear I tried everything...

So I got this exercise:

I want to add employee objects of class Employee to my list and print it's content using method. In class Company at the loop `for(int i=0; i<employeeList.size(); i++)` I got unexpected token at `for`, cannot resolve symbol 'size' at `employeeList.size();`and unknown class:'i', identifier expected, unexpected token at `i++`. In run `company.showEmployees` cannot resolve symbol 'company.

It makes me feel bad but I have absolutely no idea what to do with that...

```
public class Employee {

    protected String name;
    protected String surname;
    protected int dateOfBirth;
    protected int experience;

    public Employee(String name, String surname, int dateOfBirth, int experience) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.experience = experience;
    }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Company {

    public Company(List<Employee> employeeList) {
        this.employeeList = employeeList;
    }

    public static List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    Company company = new Company(employeeList);

    for(int i=0; i<employeeList.size(); i++) {
        employeeList.add(new Employee("Mariusz "," Kowalski ",1996,5));
        employeeList.add(new Employee("Krzysztof ", " Nowak ", 1990, 5));
        employeeList.add(new Employee("Robert ", " Klimczyk ", 1985, 10));
    }

    public static void showEmployees() {
        for(int i=0; i<employeeList.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(employeeList.get(i));
    }
}


public class Run {

    public static void main (final String[] args) {

        company.showEmployees();

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: Your for-loop needs to be inside a method. It can't be written outside.

Comment: Oh, and you've got a bunch of code in your `Company` class that's not in a method.  Big no-no.

Comment: Your `Company` has a `Company` inside it, and it has a `Company` etc until you run out of stack space. Make `employeeList` non-static and I don't see why you need to pass it in the constructor. Also never set a static field in a constructor from a parameter.

Comment: Move the for loop to your `main` method. Also the size will be `0` to start with so your loop doesn't do anything even if it compiled and I suspect you don't need it there.

Comment: No no it's not homework. I mean... I'm teaching myself java and this exercise i thought of based on things i learned already to utilize it's use.
Thanks for many answers by far, I'm going to try your fixes.

Comment: @KrzysztofIbisz - For the purposes as asking an SO question, that is equivalent to homework.  The "homework" do's abd don't apply here too.  (This is not about cheating, etc. It is about helping / encouraging people to do programming "learning exercises" in a way that will maximize the learning experience.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have statements (such as a `for` loop) outside of a method.

Maybe it should go into the constructor in your case? Or into the main method?

And why is the `employeeList` static? That would mean that all companies share the same group of employees.

Comment: Also, why are there spaces around some of the employee names? That will mess up sorting and comparisons.